# Changing extension's settings

Tags: css, syntax-highlighting

I'm using a Color Theme extension- Atom One Dark. I'm very satisfied with it, but of course, nothing in the world can satisfy a person.

And so, the issue I found with this extension is that it doesn't syntax-highlight CSS attributes'. For example:
[font-size, color, border attributes' colors are not changing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzNSH.png).

So, here I'm, asking If I can change the extension's settings my way, or copy the extension and then change its settings or any similar way that can help me with the fix.

Thank you for reading, have a fine day! :)

Comment: Okay, so I got https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#color-formats from somewhere but what is the key for the JSON settings file?